# E2316 in using std::function

Tags: c++builder

My environment: RadStudio XE4 Update1 on Windows7pro (32bit)

I am trying to study placeholder following the page
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders

Following is the code, I am trying to compile.

```
...

#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

...

static void goodbye(const std::string &s)
{
    std::cout << "Goodbye " << s << std::endl;
}

class Object {
public:
    void hello(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello " << s << std::endl;
    }
};


void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // [bcc32 error] ...:E2316 'function' is not a member of 'std'
    typedef std::function<void(const std::string &)> ExampleFunction;
}
```

In the above code, I get E2316 error in the typedef sentence.

What should I do to correct for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work in bcc32. Firstly bcc32 is not C++11-compliant, so you have to use `boost::function`.

Secondly, bcc32 does not support the specification `void(const std::string &)` ( [QC 126470](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=126470) ).

There isn't a workaround. You'll have to abandon the idea of `std::function` entirely and roll your own solution (perhaps using the bcc32 extension `__closure`).

It should work in bcc64.